# issue about Admob,Android

Tags: android

Is there any chance to try Admob without paying a fee,all I want to display some ads in my app on Android.
Admob did ask me about my payment and local tax id and other info...
Please help and any comments are welcomed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't ask my payment. The local tax id field is optional but it's useful when you get payment from Admob. You don't have to pay for it if you want to be only a publisher.

Comment: It is for your payment from Admob, but i use PayPal and fill only the PayPal login.